# . The equation $x^3 +10 x^2 − 100 x + 1729 = 0$ has at least one complex root $α$ such that $ | α | > 12$.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Show that the equation,

$x^3+10x^2−100x+1729=0$ has at least one complex root $z$ such that $|z|>12$.

Comment: Does a real root count as a complex root? If not then it seems not to be true.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Note that $1728=12^3$

and if the $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the three roots with  $\text {modulus }\le 12$
Then we have
$$|x_1x_2x_3|\le 12^3$$ 
$$x_1x_2x_3=(-1)^31729\implies |x_1x_2x_3|=+1729 $$

[See Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2B10x%5E2%E2%88%92100x%2B1729)

[**Note: The field of complex numbers includes the field of real numbers as a subfield.**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexNumber.html)

Comment: It rather depends on whether the real root of about $-19.6$ is counted as a complex root.

Comment: it is a matter of style.  Real numbers can be represented as complex numbers with zero imaginary part, but some people would regard a complex root as being in contrast to a real root.